# how to integrate Kotlin Multiplatform Mobile with Amazon amplify services?

Tags: android, ios, kotlin, aws-amplify, kotlin-multiplatform

I am raising this to just get inputs from community if there is any lib which I can use for integrating Amazon's amplify services in KMM? Also I have searched but there is no specific SDK or lib for KMM as of now.
So any input would be helpful on this.

Comment: Did you manage to solve this issue and integrate Amplify into KMM? I have this problem myself and would really appreciate it if you could share how you solved it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Amplify team is currently investing in ***Flutter*** as a multi-platform offering. Support for Flutter had been one of our [top feature requests](https://github.com/aws-amplify/amplify-js/issues/1852). Amplify Flutter became [generally available as of February 15th, 2021](https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2021/02/announcing-general-availability-amplify-flutter-data-authentication-support/). Amplify Flutter currently supports iOS & Android. Customers have additionally expressed interest for Flutter [on the Web](https://github.com/aws-amplify/amplify-flutter/issues/234) and [on the Desktop](https://github.com/aws-amplify/amplify-flutter/issues/133).

We don't currently have any plans to support **Kotlin Multiplatform** (or Multiplatform **Mobile**.) That said, we are an open source project, and love to see community contributions. You could build something on your own.

To do so, I'd start by defining a Kotlin-language API surface for the library. You can probably use [the Kotlin-language facade for the Android library](https://github.com/aws-amplify/amplify-android/pull/1057) as a starting point. From there, you can add platform bindings to Amplify Android, iOS, and JavaScript.

As a final note: the Amplify products are intended as a **front-end framework**. Therefore, it's unlikely that we we'll ever prioritize a full multi-platform build. But if we see enough customer demand, we could potentially add more explicit support for Multiplatform Mobile.

Source: I am an engineer on the Amplify team.

Comment: This clears my doubt about. Thank you for showing a way to the solution which I should definitely try. Thank you for your answer.

Comment: @FatinWasta Come chat with the Amplify on team on our Discord chat server if you want to discuss further. https://discord.gg/amplify

Comment: Hey Jameson, Thank you for channel link. Just read your comment on Github. Sorry for inconvenience caused. I ma joining this channel now.

Comment: @Jameson what about Kotlin-JS specifically? It's not necessarily part of a multi-platform solution as it can be run in isolation. I'm not sure how I could even configure it manually as the admin tool just gives me a command to run; I can't see the dependency:version to add or anything.